# add keypress code to VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I am newbie in vb.net and I am creating a code for my assignment. Please help me to add keypress code to it :( I created the interface and it runs perfectly without keypress code but then I added a keypress code, error comes out :(
All I want to do is to add a keypress code that when I press enter, the output of lblGreet is "Jolly Morning (insert person's name)" and when I press enter again the output of lblGreet is without the name of that person.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    lblGreet.Width = Me.Width
    lblGreet.Top = (Me.Height / 2) - (lblGreet.Height / 2)
    lblGreet.Left = (Me.Width / 2) - (lblGreet.Width / 2)

    lblWelcome.Width = 800
    lblDate.Top = 50
    lblDate.Left = 50

    lblTime.Top = 100
    lblTime.Left = 50

    Timer1.Enabled = True
    Me.Location = New Point(0, 0)
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim hour As Integer = DateTime.Now.Hour
    lblDate.Text = Date.Now.ToLongDateString
    lblTime.Text = Date.Now.ToLongTimeString

    If hour >= 12 And hour < 18 Then
        lblGreet.Text = "Jolly Afternoon!"
    ElseIf hour < 12 And hour >= 0 Then
        lblGreet.Text = "Jolly Morning!"
    ElseIf hour >= 18 And hour <= 24 Then
        lblGreet.Text = "Jolly Evening!"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It would help if you told us what *error come out*. What exactly is the error, and which line causes it to happen?

Comment: There's no indication that you have handled a useful event, so it's no surprise that you're not seeing the desired behaviour. You should take a look at the events related to keyboard entry, most notably `KeyDown` and `KeyPress`, although there are others too.

Comment: sorry but I already deleted the code and started a new one (that is the code above) i am new in learning VB and the keypress code confuses me :(

Comment: Then you need to do some research to reduce that confusion. I know for a fact that there are plenty of examples around of reacting to the Enter key. Showing us code that doesn't even attempt to do what you want to do is useless. Once you think you know what to do, try to do it. If it doesn't work, THEN post a question here and show THAT code. Also, include an explanation of exactly how its behaviour differs from your expectation.